# HTAccess Watermarking Rewrite, New Webhoster Not Working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, watermark

I've been using an automated watermarking PHP file (Fasthosts) which adds text when an image is rendered. I recently switched to 1&1 and activated HTTPS.
I belieive that the watermarking file might not be executed and that the .HTAccess RewriteRule is failing in some way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.jpe?g$ ../custom/watermarking/watermark.php?text=Copyright+©+2017+of+My+Images+by+My+Tours [QSA,L,NC]
```

Has worked on Fasthosts with standard HTTP access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the RewriteRule and relative locations. Changed warkmarking directory from a relative to an absolute location:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.jpe?g$ /custom/watermarking/watermark.php?text=Copyright+©+2017+of+My+Images+by+My+Tours [QSA,L,NC]
```